# Issue with minifying transpiled `jsx` code into browser readable format

Tags: reactjs, webpack, minify, bundling-and-minification, babel-loader

I have to host a `js` file on a server to be imported into any html page.
We have written some react components for the same purpose.

When we import the un-minified `js` file in the `html`, it works fine.

But, when we use the minified `js` file, it doesn't work. That means, it doesn't show anything in the browser.

We are using `webpack` for bundling the react components. `yarn build`

Babel-loaders to transpile the `jsx` code to `js`

I have tried to manually transpile the `jsx` code and then minify it. In this case the minified file also works.

But, it doesn't work when I transpile it through the my project config.

The difference between the manually minified and the projects minified file was that the manually minified file has the reference of the `js` files where React components  are written.

## .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["latest"],
    "es2015",
    "flow",
    "react",
    "stage-2",
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-dynamic-import",
  ],
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-react-remove-prop-types",
        "transform-react-inline-elements"
      ]
    },
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-react-jsx-source"
      ]
    },
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        ["latest"],
        "es2015",
        "flow",
        "react",
        "stage-2",
      ],
      "plugins": [
        "syntax-dynamic-import",
        "transform-react-jsx-source"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

## webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const paths = require('./webpack.paths.js');
const loaders = require('./webpack.loaders.js');
const plugins = require('./webpack.plugins.js');

module.exports = {
  entry: [path.resolve(paths.embed, 'index.js')],
  output: {
    path: paths.productionRoot,
    filename: 'filename.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: Object.assign({}, {
      'react': 'preact-compat',
      'react-dom': 'preact-compat',
    }),
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      loaders.eslint,
      loaders.iFrameJs,
      loaders.css,
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    plugins.environmentVariables,
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the webpack config and removed the below piece of code.

```
alias: Object.assign({}, {
   'react': 'preact-compat',
   'react-dom': 'preact-compat',
}),
```

The `react` and `preact` version mismatch was causing the problem.

## New webpack config

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: [path.resolve(paths.embed, 'index.js')],
  output: {
    path: paths.productionRoot,
    filename: 'termly.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      loaders.eslint,
      loaders.js,
      loaders.css,
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    plugins.environmentVariables,
  ],
};
```

## This solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem with .babelrc file configuration.
Would you please give a try using @babel/preset-react as recommended on babeljs site? https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react 
Example :

> npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react

.babelrc file (Usage)

> {   "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"] }